# Why does $("body") == $("body") return false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How come the equation in the title is false? How do check if two jQuery selectors point to the same DOM object?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You are comparing two *distinct* jQuery objects because you call `$()` twice (once for each side of the equation), and [as MooGoo explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316878/jquery-body-body-is-false/4316897#4316897) jQuery creates new wrapper objects for each time you call it. That's why the comparison ends up returning false.

You can extract a DOM object from each jQuery object by either using [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) or array dereferencing, then compare these elements. The following both return true because both identical selectors match the same `body` DOM element:

```
$('body').get(0) == $('body').get(0)
$('body')[0] == $('body')[0]
```

If you want to test against a jQuery selector, use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is). Note that, unless your selectors are identical, the selectors you use may not necessarily match the same DOM elements (it's still better to use the above). This also returns true:

```
$('body').is('body')
```

Comment: The first sentence is only clear if you already know that the $() function creates NEW objects, so MooGoo's answer is a little more explanatory.  If I have `function a() { return true; }`, then `a() == a()` is true.

Comment: In case it's not clear above, `is` does not test equality, it tests if at least one element in the set matches the given selector. Eg `$('#cb').is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 35):

Because jQuery creates a new wrapper object for each `$` call, and in Javascript all objects are distinct, even if they have the exact same properties/methods.

On the other hand, `document.body == document.body` would evaluate to `true`.

Comment: You were first to explain the wrapper object creation. +1

Answer (score 11):

Use $.is()

http://api.jquery.com/is/

> *Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return `true` if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments*...
>
> Unlike other filtering methods, `.is()` does not create a new jQuery object. Instead, it allows you to test the contents of a jQuery object without modification. This is often useful inside callbacks, such as event handlers...

Comment: See other answers for actual explanation for why you need $.is().