# Is it possible to get the same datepicker by different selectors (jquery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-datepicker

this might be a basic question about jquery, but I hope someone will clarify for me anyway.

I have created two datepickers on my page (pseudo-code):

```
<input id="datepicker1" class="datepicker"/>
<input id="datepicker2" class="datepicker" />

jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

if I do jQuery("#datepicker1") will I then get the same datepicker-instance which was created using the class-selector?

(I have tried the above because I need to add "onSelect" to datepicker1, but it does not work.)

thanks
Thomas

Comment: Calling `jQuery()` (or `$()`) always returns a new jQuery instance (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316878/jquery-body-body-is-false/4316904#4316904) for an explanation). However you should still obtain the same DOM element, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I do jQuery("#datepicker1") will I then get the same
>   datepicker-instance which was created using the class-selector?

Sure thing (as @BoltClock points out, you will retrieve the same DOM element that the datepicker was applied to). Here's how you could define an event handler for just one of those datepicker inputs:

```
jQuery("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "onSelect", function() {
    alert('select');
});
```

The event handler will only be fired for `#datepicker1`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/TsHwa/

---

Here's an alternate way of only executing code in `onSelect` for the `input` with id `datepicker1`:

```
jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        if (this.id === 'datepicker1') {
            alert('select');
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rdxy6/

Comment: I have attached datepicker to some HTML textboxes using CSS class name & `onSelect` event handler I need to know the selector class name on which current `onSelect` happened.. the elements have 2 other classes applied other then the one I am using to attach datepicker